# Execute functions sequentially without blocking ui, in a loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I need to execute 3 functions one after the other. One as to wait for the other to execute. That is also nested in a loop. How can I make the loop wait for the last task to finish before looping.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    private void Foo()
    {
        string[] files = GetFilesFromDir(@"C:\Bar\");
        if (files == null || files.Length < 0) { return; }

        for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            tbSked.Text = files[i];
            Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>LoadFile());
            t1.ContinueWith((a) => SQLUpdate());
            t1.ContinueWith((b) => RestartTimer());
        }
    }
```

Wich works(does not freeze UI) but it goes trough the loop as soon as executed.

Comment: Why don't you just put normal calls to all the functions into another function, and just start that new single function in a task?

Comment: Wait, do you want to block at each iteration, or you want `Foo` to wait until everything is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
private void Foo()
{
    Task.Run(() => NormalMethod());
}

private void NormalMethod()
{
    string[] files = GetFilesFromDir(@"C:\Bar\");
    if (files == null || files.Length < 0) { return; }

    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        tbSked.Text = files[i];
        LoadFile();
        SQLUpdate();
        RestartTimer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this.

```
private async void Foo()
{
    string[] files = GetFilesFromDir(@"C:\Bar\");
    if (files == null || files.Length < 0) { return; }

    for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        tbSked.Text = files[i];
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>LoadFile());
        t1.ContinueWith((a) => SQLUpdate());
        var continuationTask = t1.ContinueWith((b) => RestartTimer());
        await continuationTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. You define a task in a loop, and it just runs the loop. If you want to make the loop run the tasks one by one, I suggest starting a new `Thread`, run the whole loop in that thread, and forget about tasks. For example:

```
private void Foo()
{
    string[] files = GetFilesFromDir(@"C:\Bar\");
    if (files == null || files.Length < 0) { return; }
    new Thread(()=>{
      for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
      {
        tbSked.Text = files[i]; //if this one is a text box, dispatch it in the main thread.
        LoadFile();
        SQLUpdate();
        RestartTimer();
      }
    }).Start();
}
```